# Upload contact to Salesforce Marketing Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, fuel, mobilepush-android

I am trying to push contact in Mobile Push app. I am getting following errror when I select the file in upload wizard -

error: {"message":"**The source file identifier was not found in the Files collection**.\r\n Source: chosen-file\r\n Destination: file://ETFTP/import/597d0f01-f8e1-41a3-b0f3-0691be1b0234.csv","description":"System.Exception: The source file identifier was not found in the Files collection.\r\n Source: chosen-file\r\n Destination: file://ETFTP/import/597d0f01-f8e1-41a3-b0f3-0691be1b0234.csv - from Jint\r\n\r\n"}

The format of the file is as below -

_MobileNumber,_LastName,_FirstName,_Email,_CountryCode,_SubscriberKey
15555555555,Cruz,Angel,acruz@example.com,US,15555555555

Please do let me know if there are any resolutions for this.

Thanks,
Vineet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the error message you gave us it seems that MobilePush was unable to find the file in the source location that you specified.  This may be occurring because the file you are trying to import is not located on the FTP site specified in your Source.

I would recommend contacting Global Support to ensure that your file is in the correct location.  Their contact information is located here http://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/contact_us/.  If you are working on behalf of a client, get their assistance to open a support case with our team.